# What is a "remote access profile" in RAS?

Tags: rras, nps

I am trying to understand how RRAS and NPS work together so I can see if it would make sense to implement the two in our environment and I see references in one of the Sybex books using the term "Remote Access Profile".

I have also come across statements such as "Link a Day-And-Time-Restrictions policy to an active Remote Access Profile". I have not been able to find such an explicit "profile" item in either RRAS or NPS.

> 1.What is it referring to?

Furthermore, in the NPS console, there are connection request policies and network access policies. I find this topic, or at least the way it's explained in the book confusing.

> 2.Does the first refer to rules for establishing a connection to begin
>   with and the second to allowing access
>   to resources if and after the
>   connection is established?
>
> 3.With NPS being the Microsoft implementation of RADIUS, why would
>   you need a RADIUS Client/Proxy if you
>   can send the authentication requests
>   directly to the RADIUS Server?